# Why does removing files from a kubernetes pod file system reduce the pod's memory footprint?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, cadvisor

I deleted about 7GB of files from a pod running in kubernetes. When I checked the pod's memory usage in Kibana, it had dropped significantly:

[image]

The statistic used here to measure memory is `kubernetes.container.memory.usage.bytes`:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/exported-fields-kubernetes.html

The pod is idle.

Comment: What kind of files did you delete?

Comment: @Val: they are files generated by the application running on the container.

Comment: On average how big is each file?

Comment: You mean the container log files? What command are you using to delete those files?

Comment: Each file is 7MB. They are not log files. The application writes records of transactions it has processed to disk, and I am just deleting those. I am deleting with: rm *

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], including enough of your application's source code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @eeijlar, do you know if the container will keep the files open, or frequently (re-)open these files for random read?

Comment: The files should be closed once they reach the 7MB size. It's using a log4j appender to write the files.

Comment: Since your graph doesn't contain any title of what it's showing, are you sure it is about memory consumption and not disk consumption?